# Highcharts stock animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can stop chart animations via mouse click?

Starting it via mouse-click is fairly easy....

```
events : {
    click : function (e) {       
        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series1 = this.series[0];
        var series2 = this.series[1];
        var series3 = this.series[2];
        setInterval(function () {
            series1.addPoint(u1Array[i], true, true);
            series2.addPoint(u2Array[i], true, true);
            series3.addPoint(u3Array[i], true, true);
            i++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually means: stop/resume it on mouse-click...

Comment: Do you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/j26x89y0/ ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways of packaging this all up and it may need some massaging to work as I didn't have a full example to test against, but as a starter for 10...

**First:** In order to clear the timer you've set, you need a variable to store it in (as per http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp), so my first attempt at that is to create an 'interval' object in what I assume is a wider chart object - if I had a complete version of your problem I'd test that this works properly... not sure if `interval` needs to be even more global.

**Second:** The logic of your click function needs to change depending on whether or not it's currently running... so given that functions can be passed as variables I've defined two functions that swap each other in... *really* would like to have tested this first before posting as an answer! (Not unlikely that I've made some massive syntax error!)

**Finally:** I'd be concerned about the scope of `i` - it might start again from 0 once you click for the third time (again, something I'd like to test!) so I've put that in its own variable in the chart object too.

So...

```
events : {
    click : this.start
},

interval: null,

i: 0,

start: function(e){
    var series1 = this.series[0];
    var series2 = this.series[1];
    var series3 = this.series[2];
    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
        series1.addPoint(u1Array[this.i], true, true);
        series2.addPoint(u2Array[this.i], true, true);
        series3.addPoint(u3Array[this.i], true, true);
        this.i++;
    }, 1000);
    this.events.click = this.stop;
},

stop: function(e){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.events.click = this.start;
}
```